# PHP echoing an Array and splitting it up

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently getting dates from a web page by using the following

```
foreach($returned_content->find('div.box-inset') as $article) {
    $item['dates'] = $article->find('div.important-dates', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

var_dump($articles);
```

Which will output the following

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["dates"]=> string(235) " Important Dates Expires On October 28, 2013 Registered On October 29, 2012 Updated On October 29, 2012 " } [1]=> array(1) { ["dates"]=> NULL } }
```

I would ideally like to get the results to lay out as listed like so

- Important Dates
- Expires On October 28, 2013
- Registered On October 29, 2012
- Updated On October 29, 2012

But I am lost with getting the content to echo correctly as `echo $articles` just produces `Array` and I have never had such an Array before like this one

Comment: I was very happy to see that you are using a parser to process HTML (rather than a regex, which many people seem to think is acceptable)... but then I find you're having trouble with trivial array access and simple string manipulation... It seems a bit of an oxymoron ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
echo $articles[0]["dates"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($returned_content->find('div.box-inset') as $article) {
    $item['dates'] = $article->find('div.important-dates', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item['dates'];
}
```

you cannot use echo to output array

```
foreach($articles as $strarticle)
{
 echo $strarticle;
}
```